# Trying to convert existing WCF service to Web Role can't deploy without errors

Tags: azure-cloud-services

I've converted existing WCF application to web role by adding it with "Add web role project in solution". Convert menu doesn't offer me option to convert. Our application requires .NET 4.6.1

Application runs fine on full emulator. However deployment fails with two scenarios:

- osFamily attribute set to "5" in Serviceconfiguration(no .NET 4.6.1 installation script required):

> 19:15:16 - Instance 0 of role Severa.API is restarting
>       Details:  [11/28T17:15Z]Failed to load role entrypoint.  System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly entryPointAssembly)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum) Last exit time: [2016/11/28, 17:15:06.916]. Last exit code: 0.

- osFamily attribute set to "4" in Serviceconfiguration with .NET 4.6.1 installation:

> The feature named NetFx451 that is required by the uploaded package is not available in the OS * chosen for the deployment.

I've used the .NET installation script in other projects with success. Also I have added WebRole.CS class to the project.

Is the issue here that the webrole is not WCF type meaning some setting etc. is missing?

Answer (score 1):

We've managed to identify and fix the issue.

I've enabled Fusion logging and immediately got the missing information.
What would have saved a lot of time and point us to right direction would have been to understand that web role in CS consists of two processes: WAIISHost which runs RoleEntryPoint code in startup and good old W3WP for the Web application itself.

WAIIShost can't read Web.config and requires an empty Web.config file named after name of the project and redeployed successfully. I followed instructions from this article:

[Post about the issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2015/09/06/cloud-services-roles-recycling-with-the-error-system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/)